# Vertical rulings for a cylinder

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

Which produces this image.

[image: cylinder]

I do want mesh lines parallel to the z-axis, which all of these are, but there is an ugly overlap here. What I really want is some equally spaced mesh lines parallel to the z-axis.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use `RevolutionPlot3D[]` instead to generate your cylinder?

Comment: The most natural representation for use in a `RevolutionPlot3D` does not work well because the needed function involved `DiracDelta` functions or other poses problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without changing your choice of `ContourPlot3D`, you can achieve the desired effect by using the following `MeshFunctions` option:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 MeshFunctions -> (ArcTan[#1, #2] &), AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: cyl]

You simply have to convert the arguments of the function (which are the x and y coordinates) to an angle around the z axis, using `ArcTan`.

Comment: Perfecto! Exactly what I needed. I'd like to thank the others for their suggestions, RevolutionPlot3D, ParametricPlot3D, but right now I am writing an activity introducing students to ContourPlot3D.

Comment: @Guess who it is. Thank yo for the edit...

Comment: Yo welcome, of corse. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], z}, 
{\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]